# Chrome Push Notification Allow for all subdomain by domain

Tags: google-chrome, push-notification

If i allow chrome push notification on www.xyz.com then it will not ask for push notification permission on blog.xyz.com.

My www.xyz.com is on http and blog.xyz.com is on https.
so i can not register service worker on http.

I want to ask for push notification permission on www.xyz.com and then in popup window open blog.xyz.com and register service-worker. but on blog.xyz.com  it again ask for push notification permission .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will ask for all subdomain,there are no way to allow all subdomains

Comment: It would be great if you could improve the answer a bit (i.e. emphasize on google's security policies or other reasons for this restriction)